# How to visualize sticky-keys status under windows 10

Tags: windows-10, macos, accessibility, sticky-keys

I am having trouble with my hands, so I am trying sticky-keys on Windows 10 at work and OSX at home. Under OSX, a popup appears on the display to indicate modifier key status. I would dearly love the same feature under Windows 10. It does not appear to be a control panel option.

Can anyone suggest how to enable such a feature under windows 10, or suggest a third party tool to provide the feature?

Answer (score 0):

The sticky-keys icon in the task bar shows sticky keys status. It is enabled in the Control Panel under Keyboard. If you auto hide the task bar, you will not see the icon changing as sticky-keys works.